# Abstracting away Go types without using interfaces

Tags: go

I'm forking and extending some 3rd-party code, to add an alternative implementation of some type. Emphasis on the fact that it's external code that I'm not the owner of, so I want to keep changes minimal and very localized, to reduce maintenance burden of the fork.

The minimum possible example is that I want to go from this with a `Data` type ...

```golang
type Data struct{ x int }
func (d *Data) work() { d.x += 10 }

type API struct{}
var api = &API{}
func (api *API) newData() *Data {
    return &Data{1}
}

func OtherCode() {
    // Example user code that should be kept unmodified.
    var data *Data = api.newData()
    data.work()
    fmt.Println(data.x) // 11
}
```

... to something where `API.newData()` now returns a new `*Data` type composed of either of 2 possible types: *DataA* (the original one) and *DataB* (the newly added one), and **without causing a lot of modifications to the rest of the code**.

This includes having `*Data` passed around as arguments in methods, or having its struct fields accessed. Which is represented by the example `OtherCode()` function.

Hiding *DataA* and *DataB* behind a common `type Data interface` is insufficient, because: 1) it only provides access to methods, not value fields, so direct accesses such as `data.x` become invalid. 2) requires to change every `*Data` appearance to `Data`, otherwise the compiler complains.

**How could this be accomplished with Go 1.21?**

I.e. how could a new type `Data` be written such that it contains either a value of `DataA` (the original) or `DataB` (the new one), while the rest of the code (like `OtherCode()`) can still transparently access methods and fields *without changes* (or with the absolute minimum amount of them)?

---

Things I tried:

I came up with this mix of struct embedding and generics, which got me *almost* there:

```golang
type DataA struct{ x int }
func (d *DataA) work() { d.x += 10 }

type DataB struct{ x int }
func (d *DataB) work() { d.x += 100 }

type DataFunc interface {
    work()
}

type Data[T DataA | DataB] struct {
    DataFunc
    value *T
}

// API is extended to choose between original or new data type.
type API struct{}
var api = &API{}
func (api *API) newData() *Data {
                        // ^^^^
                        // cannot use generic type without instantiation

    // Assume this is false.
    if config.UseA {
        d := &DataA{1}
        return &Data[DataA]{
            DataFunc: d,
            value:    d,
        }
    } else {
        d := &DataB{2}
        return &Data[DataB]{
            DataFunc: d,
            value:    d,
        }
    }
}

// This code MUST NOT CHANGE.
// It's actually a lot of 3rd-party code and I don't want to change it all.
func OtherCode() {
    var data *Data = api.newData()
           // ^^^^
           // cannot use generic type without instantiation

    data.work()
    fmt.Println(data.value.x) // 102, if it compiled...
}
```

- With having `DataFunc interface` embedded into `Data`, we get transparent access to the *DataA* or *DataB* methods.
- Having a generic `value *T` is something I wanted to avoid, but I'd begrudgingly accept it if there was no other way to provide access to fields. So far that seems the case.

If both `data.work()` and `fmt.Println()` were moved to **inside** `newData()` (e.g. before the returns), then this code *works as intended*. But as soon as I do as shown, and try to return the variable, Go complains about it:

> cannot use generic type Data[T DataA | DataB] without instantiation

WHich ruins the solution, because `OtherCode()` shouldn't know or even care about how the data is constructed. Changing all appearances of `Data*` to now make it a parameterized generic is far from the desired outcome.

Comment: What you're describing is not possible. Code cannot accept a set of types without knowing it's accepting some kind of abstraction over those types.

Answer (score 2):

The direct things you're asking for aren't possible. But you may be able to do something like this to get what you want:

```golang
type Data struct {
  *OldData
  New *NewData
}
```

Embedding `*OldData` means that existing functions can access the same fields and methods. New functions will have to use `Data.New.Field` or methods added to `Data`.

Comment: This won't work because `OtherCode()` would break when accessing `data.x`. All code would need to change and a conditional inserted _everywhere_ just to decide whether to access `data.x` or `data.New.x`, which is opposite of the intention here. I'm afraid that Go simply doesn't allow to make such an abstraction between different struct implementations, which is a bummer.

Comment: @j1elo I'm not sure what you mean — embedding `*OldData` is what allows `OtherCode()` to work: https://go.dev/play/p/UwzEtny9ElG

Comment: You're right in that it compiles. The problem is that the NewData methods are supposed to replace the OldData ones. Like in the initial question, where `work()` is a method that incremented a value `+= 10` but in the new implementation does `+= 100`. Old code should get the new value. The decision of which implementation is used, happens when the struct is created (kind of like a factory pattern). Of course the real case is more complex: multimedia backends in an application. But I'll explore more your idea, will update here if I found it is indeed enough for what I wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out Go (as of v1.21) is not capable of abstracting away two (or more) structs without having to change all usages on already existing code.

Several decisions hinder this:

- Interfaces can already contain a pointer, which means that every and all locations that used a `*Type` need changing to `Type`, thus defeating the intention of not having to change user code.
- Interfaces only encapsulate "behaviors", ie. methods. Struct fields are not considered behaviors, thus are not accessible from interfaces. I knew this beforehand so that's why I discarded using interfaces to begin with.
- Generic type parameters cannot be embedded into structs. This would have been a great solution to cleanly create struct abstractions, as alternative to interfaces.

With the last one it would be possible to change an existing `MyType` into:

```golang
type MyType[T MyImplA | MyImplB] struct {
    T
}
```

without further changes in caller code, in order to let it access both methods and fields (`t.work()`, `t.x`). Alas, this possibility was discarded for Go 1.18, albeit it might be [considered as a proposal](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/49030#issuecomment-954336867) in the future. But looks like a hard sell.

What I ended up doing is an ugly mix of using interfaces to allow accessing the methods, and middleman pointers to allow accessing the fields. This only works because the original field was `atomic.Value`, which can be abstracted away like that:

```golang
type MyTypeFunc interface {
    work()
}

type MyTypeData struct {
    x *atomic.Value
}

type MyType struct {
    MyTypeFunc
    MyTypeData
}

if config.UseA {
    impl := &MyImplA{}

    val := &MyType{
        impl,
        MyTypeData{
            x: &impl.x,
        },
    }

    return val
}
[...]
```

Then user code can still do `val.x.Store()`/`val.x.Load()` without knowing that the implementation of `val` is either `MyImplA` or `MyImplB`.

This won't work if `x` is almost any other type that is directly assigned, such as an int or string.